# Delete pointers from a map

Tags: c++, qt

There is a map which maps `int` to `Test*`. All `Test*` pointers are allocated before assigning to the map. Then, it `delete`s pointers of map and set them to `null`. After that, It checks validity of `one`, and it is supposed to be `null`. **But**, `one` is not `null`.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QMap>
#include <QDebug>

class Test {
    QString name;
public:
    Test(const QString &name) : name(name) {}
    QString getName() const { return name; }
};

int main() {
    QMap<int, Test*> map;

    Test *one = new Test("one");
    Test *two = new Test("two");
    Test *three = new Test("three");

    map.insert(1, one);
    map.insert(2, two);
    map.insert(3, three);

    for (auto itr = map.begin(); itr != map.end(); itr++) {
        Test *x = *itr;
        if (x) {
            delete x;
            x = 0; // ** Sets null to the pointer ** //
        }
    }

    if (one) // ** Here one is not 0 ?! ** //
        qDebug() << one->getName() << endl; // ** And then here crashes ** //
}
```

I think, I missed something when `delete`*ing* them in the loop. How can it fixed?

Second question is, does it correctly `delete` the allocated pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the loop, the variable `x` is a local pointer only inside the loop. When you set that to `NULL` you don't actually set any *other* pointers to `NULL`.

What you should to is to set the reference returned by dereferencing the iterator to `NULL`:

```
*itr = nullptr;
```

This will make the pointer in the map be `NULL`, but the other pointers will still be pointing to a now deallocated memory area.

---

When you have two pointers, it kind of looks like this:

```
+-----+
| one | ---\
+-----+     |     +---------------+
             >--> | Test instance |
+-----+     |     +---------------+
|  x  | ---/
+-----+
```

If you set *one* of the pointers it looks like this:

```
+-----+
| one | ---\
+-----+     |     +---------------+
             >--> | Test instance |
+-----+           +---------------+
|  x  | 
+-----+
```

The variable `x` is `NULL` but the variable `one` still points to the object. And if the object has been deleted then dereferencing that pointer you will cause *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Probably by second question you are asking whether memory pointed by those pointers have been deallocated. When are calling delete with pointer it is deallocating the pointed memory by it. So when you try to access it further it causes a "segmentation fault". Because the variable "one" becomes a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Atique: Yes, thanks, suspecting to Qt, I missed this simple issues about pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to delete all would be:

```
qDeleteAll(map);
```